# How to link child and parent ids using BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, parent-child

Let's say I have the following table:

```
child_id   parent_id 
1          2
2          3
3          -
4          5
5          6
6          -
7          8
```

and I want to create the following table:

```
child_id   parent_id   branch_id
1          2           1
2          3           1
3          -           1
4          5           2
5          6           2
6          -           2
7          8           3
```

in which the branch_id denotes groupings that are linked together by the parent_ids.

However, the *row order is not guaranteed* and *branches may contain hundreds of rows*. This rules out a simple use of the LAG() function.

How can I achieve this given the limitations of BigQuery's SQL?

Comment: BigQuery does not support recursive CTEs or functions.  However, you could do what you want either by changing the data structure (by including the full path to the top) or using scripting (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below example of how to employ BigQuery Scripting for such cases

```
DECLARE rows_count, run_away_stop INT64 DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMP TABLE input AS 
  SELECT 1 child_id, 2 parent_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 8 ;

CREATE TEMP TABLE ttt AS 
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT val FROM UNNEST([child_id, IFNULL(parent_id, child_id)]) val ORDER BY val ) arr FROM input;

LOOP
  SET (run_away_stop, rows_count) = (SELECT AS STRUCT run_away_stop + 1, COUNT(1) FROM ttt);

  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE ttt AS
  SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr) arr FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(arr) val ORDER BY val) arr
    FROM (
      SELECT ANY_VALUE(arr1) arr1, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(arr) arr    
      FROM (
        SELECT t1.arr arr1, t2.arr arr2, ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT val FROM UNNEST(ARRAY_CONCAT( t1.arr, t2.arr)) val ORDER BY val) arr 
        FROM ttt t1, ttt t2 
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(t1.arr) val JOIN UNNEST(t2.arr) val USING(val)) > 0
      ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr1)
    )
  ) GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', arr);

  IF (rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ttt) AND run_away_stop > 1) OR run_away_stop > 10 THEN BREAK; END IF;
END LOOP;

SELECT input.*, branch_id
FROM input 
JOIN (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS branch_id, arr AS IDs FROM ttt
)
ON child_id IN UNNEST(IDs)
```

with final output

```
Row child_id    parent_id   branch_id    
1   7           8           1    
2   4           5           2    
3   6           null        2    
4   5           6           2    
5   3           null        3    
6   2           3           3    
7   1           2           3
```

Comment: Fantastic Mikhail, BigQuery has much greater functionality then I realised. I will have to spend some time understanding how this works.

Comment: Hello @Mikhail Berlyant, I get an "error" in this code when I apply it to a problem without the NULLs. In other words, there are plenty of chains in the data, but the NULL can't be used as a signal to indicate a chain ends.  Should it work on such a problem?

Comment: i see. above answer was tailored based on specific question and data example you presented. Please post new question with all details and logic you want to apply and I will be glad to answer it.

Comment: I will look into it :o)

Comment: Hello @ Mikhail Berlyant I have been doing some further testing and I now believe your algorithm works fine, but we had dodgy data in our system. I also couldn't get your code to fail with demo data and I tried quite hard! I will delete the new stackoverflow question and thanks for your time.

Comment: perfect. i didn't have chance yet to jump into that new question  - so thank you for update - it saved me time :o) really appreciate!

Comment: We now run into the following BigQuery limit:

Query exceeded resource limits. 4256 CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than 2500 CPU seconds. at [16:3]

I've split the data up into chunks to allow the code to function which is an inelegant solution as it adds artifical bounderies. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: This error is due to the [a CPU limit yoked to the size of the data loaded into memory](https://community.looker.com/sql-10/resources-exceeded-during-query-execution-in-bigquery-because-of-cartesian-product-12542) which causes the CROSS JOIN to fail. This can be solved by materialising the result of the CROSS JOIN in some manner or by following the above link's solution.